# How can I combine a BETWEEN condition with multiple LIKE expressions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I'm trying provide film titles that start with the letters "S" and "T", and have a replacement cost of 15.99 to 20.99.

I try to use this code but it still returns some data lower than 15.99 pls help.

```sql
SELECT title,length,replacement_cost
FROM film
WHERE title LIKE 'S%' OR title LIKE 'T%'
AND replacement_cost BETWEEN 15.99 AND 20.99;
```

Still returns data lower than 15.99. [See results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzM6a.png)

Tried searching for other ways to use `LIKE` with `IN` not `OR`. Maybe that's the problem but I saw a post saying that `IN` is not usable with `LIKE`.

Comment: `AND` binds stronger than `OR`. Add parentheses.

Comment: It worked, I did it like this: WHERE (title LIKE 'S%' OR title LIKE 'T%') AND (replacement_cost BETWEEN 15.99 AND 20.99) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Nath123: The second pair of parentheses you added is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your immediate problem is [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). `AND` binds before `OR` - as has been commented. Can be fixed with parentheses:

```sql
SELECT title, length, replacement_cost
FROM   film
WHERE (title LIKE 'S%' OR title LIKE 'T%')
AND    replacement_cost BETWEEN 15.99 AND 20.99
```

But you can simplify. Then you don't need `OR` and, consequently, no parentheses either:

```sql
WHERE  title LIKE ANY ('{S%, T%}')
```

And while you only match prefixes the [operator `^@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is better, yet. Requires Postgres 11; much improved in Postgres 15:

```sql
WHERE  title ^@ ANY ('{S,T}')
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: Oh okay, I'm sorry for the late reply I'll accept it it does answer my questions.